# How to Put PDF on SD card for use by Adobe Reader

Tags: sd-card, pdf

I have phone tethered to PC, and on the "G" drive I can see the phone directories and files.  Another post, said that you have to put PDF files on SD card.  How do I navigate to the SD card, is it the "DCIM" directory?  I tried putting a file there, but Adobe Reader still says "No PDF Files Available".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on Adobe PDF reader, too bad it doesn't have a simple "file open" option. 
I downloaded Beamreader free version, and so far it's working.  It actually allows you to browse the directories and open files, what a concept!

I was going to buy the Speedsoftware Explorer suggested by @Matthew above, but never bought an app before, and got this issue: 
[buy an app - message: "none of the accounts on your phone are supported"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8141/buy-an-app-message-none-of-the-accounts-on-your-phone-are-supported)

Answer (score 1):

My Adobe Reader seems to be looking in the `download` folder, try putting them there.  You could also just browse to them on your phone and open them directly.  Your phone should already have a file manager to use for that, but I recommend [Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.speedsoftware.explorer) (or Root Explorer if you have root).

Comment: I used PC to copy to download folder, and still get same message in Adobe Reader, "No PDF Files Available".  I installed a FileManager, but I don't see any correlation between the files that I see there and the "G" drive I referred to in my original post.  I am not yet very familiar with the directory structure, but ready to learn.

Comment: So for example, I do not see "downloads" in the File Manager.

Comment: Hmm.  Look at `/sdcard/external_sd/` via the file manager, does that look like your G drive?  If so try using the file manager to move the PDFs to `/sdcard/download/`.